# How to display a table with content from a database on a page? rest ajax spring boot application

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, rest

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cars Selling</title>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="listCarsSelling.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Cars Selling List</h2>

    <table id="table-content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>code</td>
                <td>manufacturer</td>
                <td>model</td>
                <td>color</td>
                <td>transmission</td>
                <td>body_type</td>
                <td>price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

listCarsSelling.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/ListCarsSelling",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                
                for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                     var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].code + '</td><td>' + data[i].manufacturer
                     + '</td><td>' + data[i].model + '</td><td>' + data[i].color + '</td><td>'
                + data[i].transmission + '</td><td>' + data[i].body_type + '</td><td>' 
                + data[i].price + '</td></tr>');
                
                    $('#table-content').append(row);
                }
            },
            
            error: function(msg){
                allert(msg.responseText);
            }
        });
})
```

photo with error '404' for reference on the link 'http://localhost:8080/':
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVBVd.png)

---

I want the data from my database to be displayed immediately when I go to the main page. How can i do this?
I also want to point out that I have no problems connecting to the database, since while developing rest i was able to extract json data. I just now need to display them somehow..

Comment: Is there any JS error in your browser console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, the problem was painfully commonplace. Incorrect project structure.
The application file was in another package, and it should be above all as shown here.
[omg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvLJy.png)